# Phonegap app works in emulator but not on a device

Tags: android, cordova, emulation, phonegap-build

I am using a mac (Yosemite) to test my app on a Samsung tablet.

There is no additional code causing this issue, I am trying to build a boilerplate Phonegap application here.

The app works fine in the emaultor when running:

```
phonegap run --emaulator.
```

However, when I run:

```
phonegap run --device
```

I get the follwoing in the terminal:

```
[phonegap] executing 'cordova run --device'...
[phonegap] completed 'cordova run --device'
```

But nothing happens on the device.

When I run:

```
phonegap run --device --verbose
```

The terminal provides a lot of feedback, with the main parts being:

```
ERROR: Failed to launch application on device: 
ERROR: Failed to install apk to device: 
ERROR: Failed to deploy to device, no devices found.
```

And

```
ERROR running one or more of the platforms: 
Error: /Users/alan/Desktop/supportright/platforms/android/cordova/run: 
Command failed with exit code 1
You may not have the required environment or OS to run this project
```

Comment: please check you have installed cordova and in system environment path content android sdk tools path and platform tools path

Comment: Make sure your device is in debugging mode and that it is actually well plugged

Comment: @SantoshShinde I have cordova/phonegap installed. Can you expand on the rest of your path requirements please?

Comment: @BipBip I have USB Debugging on (checked).

Comment: path : %ANDROID_HOME%\tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools;

Comment: @SantoshShinde What is exactly is going on here? Can you provide a detailed explanation of your suggestion, along with steps required to carry them out please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following steps too (on Yosemite):

Install Java JDK before anything else and set the JAVA_HOME environment variable:

**$ export JAVA_HOME=”/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk<-version->.jdk/Contents/Home/”**

After installing Android SDK, you need to set

ANDROID_HOME:

**$ export ANDROID_HOME=`brew --prefix android`**

**$ export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/bin**

**$ export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools**

Also add all these 'export' lines to your ~/.bash_profile

Before running the hello app in the emulator:

**$ cordova platform add android**

Comment: How exactly would I don this on OSX (Yosemite)? Thanks

Comment: and more information go here  http://www.panopticdev.com/blog2014/phonegap-mac-osx-setup-configuration-android-ios/

Comment: When I run `cordova run android --device` I get `[phonegap] executing 'cordova run --device'...
[phonegap] completed 'cordova run --device'` but nothing happens on the device? And the link you sent is one I have already been working from.

Comment: Try to connect other device and check list of devices on terminal by command :  -  adb devices

Comment: if not showing then device driver problem on your system

Answer (score 0):

If you have added the adb to the path in Yosemite, execute this in a shell to check if your device is currently recognized by your computer:

`adb devices`

If not result is returned, your android device is not being recognized by adb, and this is why the APK can't be uploaded to the tablet.

Comment: Can you expand on adding adb to the PATH please? How do I do it, or check if it is already done? When I run `adb devices` I get my device code

Comment: If you run adb devices and you get your device code, It's not a problem of the Android connection. There is a problem between Cordova and the Android SDK. Follow @Santosh advices

Answer (score 0):

Have You enabled Developer Options and USB Debugging on your Samsung?

Comment: Yes I have. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Do You have the newest Android SDK version and appropriate Build Tools version?

Comment: Yes, everything is running the latest version etc.

Comment: It says: 'ERROR: Failed to deploy to device, no devices found.'

How about missing USB drivers?

Comment: I have all the necessary drivers etc.